# additional @font-face not working? 404 error

Tags: css

I'm developing a wordpress theme with 2 @font-face.

The Century Gothic doesn't work, but the Playfair font is displaying just fine.

I appreciate any insight on why it's returning an error...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    src: url("wp-content/themes/cats-who-code/fonts/CenturyGothic.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    src: url("wp-content/themes/cats-who-code/fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your CenturyGothic.ttf isn't being found in the location you specified. I also noticed that the path is repeated when being requested from the server (wp-content appears twice). You might need to fix that first.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what I have to do though... because it has the same path as the second font, just that the file name is different..

Comment: nevermind, it works... i condensed it to fonts/CenturyGothic.tff